# Cordova run/prepare/build not doing anything, no errors

Tags: node.js, cordova, ant

I installed cordova globally via npm (nodejs version 5.1.0)
Cordova v5.2.0

When I run `cordova run android` or `cordova run` or `cordova build` it does nothing, no errors, just a blank line (in powerShell no blank line at all)
Also with option `--verbose` or `-d`

Even when I make a completely new project it won't work.

Wat *does* work is `cordova compile`, but the compiled `.apk` is an old version. Probably because `prepare` moves the latest files from `www` into the `platforms` folder.
Now I could manually copy those of course, but that's not a solution to this.

I did just freshly install android studio and jre8, i thought it might need jre7, but after installing that, no change. (changed `%PATH%` var as well)

Then I remembered that cordova needs `ant` which is never mentioned here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html 
But after adding all the right `%PATH%` variables, still the same problem. Nothing.

I've been looking for **error logs** but I can't find any (`%USERPROFILE%`/.cordova). Any suggestions where to find them?

Furthermore, node works fine for the rest

I've tried removing and re-installing cordova as well.

I do see the `npm.exe` process running for about one second.

Also, running windows 10

`javac 1.8.0_65`
`adb version 1.0.32`